# pandas read_sql used for CREATE in Postgres db giving TypeError for SQLite

Tags: pandas, postgresql

I am trying to use pandas to create functions and tables in postgres.

When I try this query:

```
conn = = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', database='my_data',
                     port='5566', user='postgres', password='postgres')

create_example = '''
    create temporary table example(id int primary key, str text, val integer);
    insert into example values
    (1, 'a', 1),
    (2, 'a', 2),
    (3, 'b', 2);
'''
pd.read_sql(create_example,conn)
```

I get the following error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`
[image]

The connection/read_sql works for simple queries but I get the error when I try to CREATE a function or table. Why am I getting the error and why does the error seem to be in SQLite when the connection is to a postgres database? tia

UPDATE: Per the observation by @AdrianKlaver I imported sqlalchemy as follows.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def db_connect():
    db_connect_string = "postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{passwd}@{server}:{port}/{db}" \
        .format(user="postgres", passwd="postgres",
    server="localhost", db="my_data", port="5566")
    return create_engine(db_connect_string)

alchemy_conn = db_connect()
```

So using this alchemy connection:

```
pd.read_sql(create_example,alchemy_conn.raw_connection())

>>TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

If I try to use the cursor function I get the error `AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' object has no attribute 'cursor'`

Comment: See here [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html): "con SQLAlchemy connectable, str, or sqlite3 connection". Since you are not using an `SQLAlchemy` connection `pandas` is trying a `sqlite3` one.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver this is a good observation but my update shows that an sqlalchemy approach is not more successful.  My intuition is that I need a cursor object which I can get with psycopg2.   However, sqlalchemy seems to be ignoring psycopg2 portion of the connect string and the 'alchemy_conn' object has no cursor attribute.

Comment: `read_sql` as the name suggests is used to *read* SQL results, not execute arbitrary queries. The SQL *script* you posted returns nothing, ie NoneType. If you wanted to create and fill a table with dataframe data, you should create the dataframe first then call `to_sql`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos tnx.  I was hoping to be able to execute arbitrary queries.  My example is a simple one to see if I could.  The fact is I'm not starting with a df, I have a large db and I'm trying to get as much done in the db as possible before downloading anything in to a df.  I was hoping pandas could execute CREATE so I could create temporary tables, pl/pgsql functions, etc.

Comment: @MikeB2019x why? Pandas isn't a database access library. That's what SQLAlchemy is for. Use SQLAlchemy's `execute` method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos unfortunately I'll have to take your advice :-)  I was hoping to avoid introducing more code/imports in to the pipeline as it's just one more dependency to worry about, one more learning curve for a future successor.

Comment: What extra imports? You already imported both psycopg2 and SQLAlchemy (through Pandas). It's *pandas* that's the extra import here. Since you already connected with `psycopg2` you can create a new cursor with `cur=conn.cursor()` and then execute your query with `cur.execute(create_example)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executing SQL query with psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48791244/executing-sql-query-with-psycopg2)

Comment: Yes it does.  But it isn't obvious to me how to use sqlalchemy to execute arbitrary sql without importing it separately.  I really wanted to avoid having the back and forth between psycopg2 <-> pandas ie. task postgres with psycopg retrieve/manipulate data with pandas.  Wishful thinking.